# User Signup to 'https://api.parse.com/1/users' giving Bad Request Error

Tags: python, django, urllib2

When I am going to post user data in users table at parse.com I am getting Bad Request Error. What is wrong with this code? Any help Plz. Here is my code

```
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        data = {"username": username, "name": name, "password": password1, "email": email}
        data = urllib.urlencode(data)
        url = settings.API_USER_ROOT
        http_verb = 'POST'
        request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        request.add_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        auth_header =  "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (settings.APPLICATION_ID, settings.MASTER_KEY))
        request.add_header("Authorization", auth_header)
        request.get_method = lambda: http_verb
        try:
            print '***************'
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            print '***********'
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print e.reason
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import httplib, json

```
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/users', json.dumps({
   "username": "cooldude6",
   "password": "p_n7!-e8",
   "phone": "415-392-0202"
 }), {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "APP ID",
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "MASTER KEY",
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
 })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
```

In order to Post at HTTPS Use Port 443